# Is there any event which will be fired when I click on a tab in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension for google chrome. I want to find the URL of the current tab, whenever I click on any tab in chrome. If I have three tabs open "abc.com","xyz.com","mnc.com" and when I click on first tab, I want an event to be fired, where I can get the current URL("abc.com"), and when clicked on the second tab,I should get the URL as "xyz.com". Is there any way to achieve this?

I am new to Chrome extensions and any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disagree with duplicate. There is no event for clicking per se, but there is an event when an active tab _changes_. Would it fit your purpose?

Comment: @Xan yep, removed my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no event that would indicate that a tab was *clicked* if it does not change the active tab. I mean, if you were on tab 1, and click it again, it will not emit any event.

There are, however, some events in the `tabs`/`windows` APIs that can approximate what you want when the active tab *changes*.

Specifically, [`chrome.tabs.onActivated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated) will alert you when the active tab changes (this includes opening a new tab that is focused).

You might also want to use [`chrome.windows.onFocusChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#event-onFocusChanged) to track switching to a window without changing the active tab.

Comment: Thank you so much Xan. "chrome.tabs.onActivated" Fits my purpose. It seems I have to use  "chrome.tabs.get" to access the Url of the activated tab. Thanks a lot for quick reply.

Comment: Don't forget you need the `"tabs"` permission to query the URLs.